# How do I run the guided tour for new users?

Tags: macos

I was suggested to start a guided tour for new users but I pressed "Don't remind me".

How can I activate this feature?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438521/how-can-i-show-whats-new-in-macos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in the Finder click on the Help menu item. One of the options is: "New to Mac? Tour the Basics". This will open a document and give you a tour of the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue when I inadvertently closed the 'Guided Tour' after updating my macOS.
I discovered that you can relaunch it without too much hassle. Just open the Finder, then click on the 'Help' menu at the top of the screen. From the drop-down options, select 'Tips for Your Mac' This action should initiate the guided tour where you can explore the new features at your leisure.