# How can I show what's new in macOS?

Tags: macos, monterey

After a fresh install, macOS Monterey opened an app showing "What's new in macOS" or something like that.
At that time I've couldn't checked but later I looked for but didn't find that app.

How can I open it again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the menu bar in Finder: **Help** → **See What's new in macOS**.

Answer (score 3):

Select `Finder > Help(from menu bar) > See What's new in macOS.`

But it is always recommended this small animation video does not elaborate on all whats new in OS. My opinion is always taking a look at Apple's official site there is a tab for the new OS and all new OS technology previews. Maybe this is a good practice.

Comment: Note that this has changed for macOS 13 (Ventura). In it's place, select "Tips for your Mac". This launches a help window with several tips collections. One of them is "What's New".

Answer (score 3):

In macOS 14.1 (Sonoma), this is now found in Tips.app.

You can access Tips.app either through the search bar search for Tips or by Navigating to **Macintosh HD > System > Library > CoreServices > Tips.app**

Comment: Thanks. Making an edit to the accepted answer also is encouraged if you want that answer to stay correct / selected.